# Not simple cart need expert answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am so surprised of getting -1 for my questions. They are not simple, they are complex.
    
 
My line_items table have product_id cart_id order_id
Whenever customer clicks on product, it is added to the cart.
But my apartment, cars, tour package are not products. Whoever is thinking that somehow I can connect to products my cars, apartments tell me. They have fundamentally different attributes. When customers clicks on apartments and chooses 2 bedroom lets say how I can add to line_items my apartment_id or car_id or tour_id. Please I don't need theory on STI or multiple inheritance. I need exactly answer. Thanks for rails expert.

Comment: the down votes are likely because you are not putting in the effort required to _ask_ a question that anyone here could _understand_ well enough to answer.  Look at other questions and you'll see people putting a lot of detail, especially examples, and showing what they have tried.  The harder the question, the more details are required.  If you look at the question above, you'll notice it assumes we understand a great deal about what you're trying to do -- there's *no context*.  Write a question that stands on its own (edit this one!) and you'll likely get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should format your question regarding to the `SO` guidelines, that's maybe because you're getting downvotes...

Anyway, I think you're looking for [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Assuming that `Product` is meant to be a product available in your shop and `LineItem` represents a product in an order:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :product  # ONE LineItem references ONE product in the shop
  belongs_to :cart  # respectively belongs_to :order
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items  # ONE Cart HAS MANY LineItems
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyable, :polymorphic => true

  # here you would have general attributes representing a product, e.g. 'name'
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :product, :as => :buyable

  # here you would have specific attributes in addition to the general attributes in
  # product, e.g. 'brand'
end

class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :product, :as => :buyable

  # here you would have specific attributes in addition to the general attributes in
  # product, e.g. 'address'
end
```

To make that work your `products` table must have the two columns

- buyable_type (string)
- buyable_id (integer)

So in your code you can check what exactly your Product is by doing

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])

if @product.buyable.is_a? Car
  puts @product.buyable.brand
elsif @product.buyable.is_a? Apartment
  puts @product.buyable.address
end
```